# 1 Query to access 2 parse classes in Swift for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift2, parse-server

I am working on an iOS app that is running Swift 2, but will be upgraded to Swift 3.

I need to access user post information from a class called `Posts` which will pull data and add them to an array, but at the same time, I need to grab the user's profile picture who's post info I am pulling as well.

Here's the tricky part, the profile image is in a column called `ava` from another class named `User`.

I want to accomplish this all in 1 query or a nested query.

I have tried multiple ways and cannot get it working.

I have asked others and they insist on creating one query for posts with another query inside of the first query and then append the ava file to the ava array I created.

Below is the code I have that crashes.

Notice `queryTwo` is where I attempted to insert the query for the class User.

```
            let query = PFQuery(className: "posts")
            query.whereKey("username", containedIn: self.followArray)
            query.limit = self.page
            query.addDescendingOrder("createdAt")
            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil {

                    let queryTwo = PFQuery(className: "_User")
                    queryTwo.whereKey("username", containedIn: self.followArray)
                    queryTwo.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                        if error == nil {

                            // clean up

                            self.avaArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

                            // find related objects
                            for object in objects! {

                                self.avaArray.append(object.objectForKey("ava") as! PFFile)

                            }

                        }
                    })

                    // clean up
                    self.usernameArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
                    self.avaArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
                    self.dateArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
                    self.picArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
                    self.titleArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
                    self.uuidArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

                    // find related objects
                    for object in objects! {
                        self.usernameArray.append(object.objectForKey("username") as! String)
                        self.dateArray.append(object.createdAt)
                        self.picArray.append(object.objectForKey("pic") as! PFFile)
                        self.titleArray.append(object.objectForKey("title") as! String)
                        self.uuidArray.append(object.objectForKey("uuid") as! String)
                    }    

                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                    self.refresher.endRefreshing()

                }
```

Comment: I assume it's too late to make a schema mod to include a User pointer as a field on the Post? That's how I would've done it to simplify things a bit for this use case. What line is causing it to crash?

Comment: Right, the crash happens much lower in the view controller file. Where I call the avaarray in the cell configuration code. Meaning, I must not be placing the queryTwo in the right place or something like that.    To be exact its this line much lower in the view controller.      avaArray[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data:NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in             cell.avaImg.image = UIImage(data: data!)         }

Comment: I would use the debugger to pinpoint exactly what line causes the code to crash. From your comment above, it sounds like the code you posted in your question is not actually what causes the crash.  Without more information it's hard to help. I noticed you don't check for an error after calling getDataInBackgroundWithBlock Maybe you're force unwrapping the data when there's no data there.

Comment: @toddg I do check for error further down in the code. But still not sure the issue. Code seems right to me. :-(

Comment: Drop a breakpoint at the top of the function listed in your question, and another one in the cell config function. Run your code and see exactly what line is causing the app to crash.